# How to use GLM in Android NDK Application

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, glm-math

I am currently trying to port my OpenGL application to Android and am stuck on how to import and build GLM http://glm.g-truc.net/ properly. I have no trouble using GLM in standard C++ apps, however I am pretty new to the NDK. I have tried all other solutions posted around the web with no luck. Here is what I have so far:

I am using the latest version of GLM (0.9.4)

My .cpp file contains:

```
    #include <glm\glm.hpp>
```

My Android.mk file looks like:

```
    LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE    := libgl2jni
    LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := gl_code.cpp
    LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -lGLESv2

    APP_STL := gnustl_static
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \Development\OpenGL\glm-0.9.4.0\

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**\Development\OpenGL\glm-0.4.0** is the location of the GLM files on my  C drive

Upon building, I receive this error:

```
   In file included from jni/gl_code.cpp:28:0,
       \Development\OpenGL\glm-0.94.0\glm\glm.hpp:86:18: fatal error: limits: No such file or directory
```

This resembles codemonkey's problem https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47128/android-ndk-build-cant-find-glm-headers where the 'APP_STL := gnustl_static' was suggested.

It appears that my source files are correctly setup, however there is some sort of compiler problem that I cannot identify. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I read elsewhere that putting APP_STL := gnustl_static into Application.mk (not Android.mk) would work.. and sure enough it did for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam Hocevar's answer to codemonkeys problem is correct. it's not glm that's the problem. It's the "limits" header file used by glm that's the problem.

If Sam's answer does not solve your problem, try changing the toolchain to an earlier version by adding the following to your Application.mk file:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.4.3
```

And make sure that the STL includes for your project in Eclipse correspond with the toolchain.
Go to project->properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols

make sure the following directories are included:

**EDIT** : these are only examples; make sure you use the correct platform and abi

```
/Path/To/NDK/sources/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include
/Path/To/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/include
/Path/To/NDK/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
```

EDIT : remark on first directory removed; seems glm looks for the limits file provided by the current stl implementation

Comment: Thanks @Erik for the quick response. After properly adding the CDT support (which I was missing), I added all the includes that you suggested.  I also made sure my target platform was consistent everywhere. Still no luck - same error! Any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest you make sure your stl paths are correct; from what I can see glm looks for the limits file provided by the currently active stl implementation.

Comment: It turns out I wasn't paying enough attention. I was adding this all to Android.mk when instead it should have been added to Application.mk as both you and Sam suggested. Works great now! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

**Follow this solution if you are using Android Studio.**

**First**, download OpenGL Mathematics library [here](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html)

**Second**, extract and copy folder "../glm/glm" to your project location at "../app/src/main/cpp"

**Third**, on CMakeList.txt, add the following:

```
# Import the CMakeLists.txt for the glm library
add_subdirectory(glm) # if your CMakeLists is at '../cpp'
# add_subdirectory(src/main/cpp/glm) # if your CMakeLists is at '../app'

# add lib dependencies
target_link_libraries(
# Specifies the target library.
native-lib
# Links the target library to the log library included in the NDK.
GLESv2
glm)
```

**Fourth**, on 'build.gradle' (module app), make sure you have right path to your CMakeList

```
 externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
 }
```

**Fifth**, include glm headers to your source file:

```
// open GL libs
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/rotate_vector.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/closest_point.hpp>
```

Sample is available at android-ndk, see [Android Endless Tunnel Game](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/endless-tunnel)