# Android ndk can't find <limits> included in glm.hpp

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, glm, gear-vr

I would like to build the sample projects included in the [gear vr framework](https://github.com/Samsung/GearVRf/tree/master/GVRf) using Android Studio on Windows 8. I imported the "simple-sample" project (GVRf\Sample\simple-sample) into Android Studio 1.5, and configured the NDK to be the latest version: **android-ndk-r10e**

However, I kept getting this error when building the project:

**limits: No such file or directory**

the < limits > header is included in glm.hpp, located at "framework\src\main\jni\contrib\glm"

Here is my **Application.mk** file inside directory "\framework\src\main\jni"

> APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
>   APP_PLATFORM := android-19
>   #APP_STL := stlport_static
>   APP_STL := gnustl_static
>   NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
>   ifndef OVR_MOBILE_SDK
>         OVR_MOBILE_SDK=../../ovr_sdk_mobile
>   endif
>   NDK_MODULE_PATH := $(OVR_MOBILE_SDK)

People suggested several ways to address this problem:
1. set NDK_TOLLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.4.3  ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859727/how-to-use-glm-in-android-ndk-application)) 
2. set APP_STL := gnustl_static  ([post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47128/android-ndk-build-cant-find-glm-headers))

I tried both and neither worked. However, it seems like the problem is that the **Application.mk** file is ignored by Android Studio. Because I typed some junk in there and it didn't seem to affect anything.

So I also tried to configure the NDK by modifying **build.gradle** file inside the \framework folder:

> android {
>    defaultConfig {
>     ndk {
>      stl "stlport_static"
>     }
>    }
>   }

Not much success either, don't know how to correctly set the values.

There is a line of words on the [Gear VR guide](http://www.gearvrf.org/bin/view/GearVRfDeveloperGuide/GearVRfDevGuide200Start) website which might be relevant (my error is indeed at the JNI level):
**NOTE: Do NOT install a CDT version higher than 8.0.2 or you will encounter parser errors at the JNI level, even though these will not affect building and running your GearVRf application.**

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest to setup your gradle to run ndk-build, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636150/define-local-src-files-in-ndk-dsl/32640823#32640823 (see the "old answer").